# Changes to a table-valued function called by a stored procedure are not recognized?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, optimization

I have a stored procedure sp that calls a table-valued function tvf. Sometimes I modify the tvf but when subsequently executing sp, the output from sp is the same as before the modification. It seems like it is cached or compiled or something. If I make some dummy change to the sp, then I get the right output of the sp.

Is there some way, I can overcome this problem? In Oracle it is possible to re-compile all stored procedures, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in SQL Server?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: altering an object (such as a TVF) should flush uses of it from the cache.

Comment: can you post the UDF and the calling TSQL...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is too large to fit in here :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sp_recompile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx) to recompile a stored procedure but afaik, what you describe shouldn't happen.

Could you post the `udf`? Only scenario I can think of would be when the `udf` always returns the same result, regardless of input parameters.

Comment: Thanks for you very prompt reply!

The udf is rather involved, so I dont expect you to have the energy to actually look at it, but anyway here it is... oh, it was about 5000 characters too long to fit here :) I will see if I can reproduce this behaviour with some simpler example. 

But I am not making this up - I have observed it several times...

Do I have to use sp_recompile for each stored procedure, or can I somehow make it recompile all my stored procedures?

Comment: I would use the output of *SELECT 'sp_recompile ' + name FROM sys.procedures* to recompile all stored procedures.